# RewriteRule get any url

Tags: mod-rewrite

what is wrong with my RewriteRule  rules:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ps1462/info_page.php?key=$1 [QSA,L]
```

When i add this line in my .htaccess file - get 500 error.
I need all characters send to new page.

Comment: Have you enabled mod_rewrite first ? With `RewriteEngine On` ?

Comment: Not turning on the RewriteEngine won't cause a 500 to be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that at least `AllowOverride FileInfo` is set in your virtualhost/httpd configuration.

And it is always a good idea to escape dots in regexp if you really mean a dot:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ps1462/info_page\.php?key=$1 [QSA,L]
```

but that would not cause the 500 internal server error...